# React + Redux + Babel (SyntaxError in ...state unexpected token)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, syntax-error, babeljs

i try to repeat the example:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async/src

But i use last versions of `React`, `Redux` and `Babel` (in example was React v15.5). I don't change anything in this example, and then i try to build it with webpack i get SyntaxError here:

```
  22 |     case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
  23 |       return {
> 24 |         ...state,
     |         ^
  25 |         didInvalidate: true
  26 |       }
```

In the `./reducers/index.js`

```
const posts = (state = {
  isFetching: false,
  didInvalidate: false,
  items: []
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
      return {
        ...state,
        didInvalidate: true
      }
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false
      }
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        items: action.posts,
        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What is wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

After **AdityaParab** answer i make:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-3
```

And in your .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "stage-3", "react"]
}
```

Last error disappeared, but i take one more in `./containers/App.js`:

```
  19 |   }
  20 |
> 21 |   handleChange = nextSubreddit => {
     |                ^
  22 |     this.props.dispatch(selectSubreddit(nextSubreddit))
  23 |   }
  24 |
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Works fine with it.

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "stage-3", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Thanks all for advice!

Comment: do you have `.babelrc`? Or you pass configuration to babel via command line?

Comment: This is an issue when you don't have correct preset

Comment: whats in your .babelrc?

Comment: @AdityaParab my .babelrc `{"presets": [ "env",  "react"] }`

Comment: {
  "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-1"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-runtime"]
}

Comment: @MichaelPloeckinger ok i will try it now

Comment: user `stage-3` preset for spread operator to work

Comment: use https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-3/ or https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.html , for better understanding of presets, plugins check this too https://stackoverflow.com/a/48516794/4061006

Comment: stage-3 is not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the preset

first

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-3
```

And in your `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "stage-3", "react"]
}
```

Comment: it is help, but now another error, i think i need some plagin, not only stage-3

Comment: this proposal is stage 4 https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread and the correct transform is https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.html

Comment: @DenisRoss can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: nvm.. I checked updated question. Yes you'd need `transform-class-properties"` for that arrow function syntax to work on arrow function class properties.

Answer (score -2):

you are going to concatenation object, so you should follow ES6 syntax.

you current syntax is wrong.

```
return {
    ...state,
    didInvalidate: true
  }
```

should be like this

```
return {
    ...state,
    ...{ didInvalidate: true }
  }
```

replace it at all case and then try again.

Comment: Your syntax would evaluate to exactly the same. The OP syntax is fine.

Comment: Yes. I see no problem with the syntax for this case. What you're saying is correct for nested objects. But this isn't one of those.